# Delete events before deleting calendar - not able to get events

Tags: api, google-apps-script, calendar

I am still learning Apps Script. here is [sample google sheet](https://009co.com/?p=881) and the code for creating calendar events from the Google sheet's custom menu. I want to add delete events & calendar functions into the menu option.

But I am not able to get the event list by the to & from date. I took help from [this link](https://009co.com/?p=881)

```js
function delete_events()
{
  //Please note: Months are represented from 0-11 (January=0, February=1). Ensure dates are correct below before running the script.
  var fromDate = new Date(); //This represents June 1st 2020
  var toDate = new Date(); //This represents June 30th 2020
  toDate.setHours(toDate.getHours()+24);
  var calendarID = 'c_9ngacs4sflij848armjj9i91dk@group.calendar.google.com'; //Enter your calendar ID here

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
   Logger.log('calendar: '+calendar.getName());
  //Search for events between fromdate and todate with given search criteria
  var events = calendar.getEvents(fromDate, toDate);
  Logger.log('Event: '+events.length);
  // events.forEach(function(e,i){Logger.log(e[i])});
  for(var i=0; i<events.length;i++) //loop through all events
  {
    var ev = events[i];
    Logger.log('Event: '+ev.getTitle()+' found on '+ev.getStartTime()); // Log event name and title
      ev.deleteEvent(); // delete event
  }
}
```

My appscript.json file has following scopes added -

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
],
```

But when I run the code above, I get following -

[image]

Then I see the actual calendar, which has full to events.

[image]

Why is that my function not working properly?
Event id, CalId is Ok. So what is the cause of empty events?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Calendar, so just a guess. It looks like the problem is with `getTitle()` function https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getTitle() Probably, I'm not sure, you need to add `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds` into your json

Comment: Actually I think the problem is that setHours() just sets the hour for that date.  So your fromDate and toDate are the same and hence no events. Try adding a day.  `toDate=new Date(newDate().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate() + 1);`

Comment: @Cooper, `setHours()` works fine for me. You can try it by yourself. Here is another similar example with `setDate()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088181/making-a-sheet-with-the-name-of-the-date-3-days-later/68089880#68089880 He can use `toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+1);` it's all the same

Comment: I guess the problem is not with adding dates or hours. I have tried all those already. I need to try some other tricks.

Comment: @yuri-khristich Thanks for the link. it is nice one.

Comment: Hello there @k.b! If the previous comments solved your question, please write an answer showing how for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using following post's code.
Here is the [link][1].
The part of the code which solved my delete event function is following -

```js
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
  event.deleteEventSeries();
  row[9] = '';  // Remove event ID    
}
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
```

Thank you all for your inputs.
[1]: [Google Script: How can I Create/Update/Delete Calendar Event and prevent duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412312/google-script-how-can-i-create-update-delete-calendar-event-and-prevent-duplica)